# Precision of AWS Kinesis PutRecord ordering

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-kinesis

[Based on the Kinesis docs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/kinesis/latest/APIReference/API_PutRecord.html), there is a 'coarse ordering' (based on time) with the `PutRecord`. What is the precision of this ordering? Seconds? Milliseconds? I can't find precision statements anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

Probably not in the documentation, but going based on a general understanding of this service:

- "Coarse" ordering is meant to be a simple way of saying they're in the order in which the server receives and internally stores them. If you have a single-threaded record producer, they'll be in the same order you send them in.
- Once you are dealing with multiple producer threads/hosts, it depends entirely on which request first made it through the network, into AWS, and into the piece of backend code that orders the requests. Even if request A is received before request B, request B may make it through the backend code faster, and thus stored faster.

Now, using that information to give a more specific answer to your question:

- Realistically, the back-end code is quite fast - a single threaded Kinesis producer with a good connection to AWS (such as EC2) can support somewhere in the range of 50-200 single-record `PutRecord` calls per second.  Based on this, it's very likely this "coarseness" is in the range of 5-20 milliseconds.

If you **need** exact ordering, consider using either a single-threaded producer and/or using the [`SequenceNumberForOrdering`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/kinesis/latest/APIReference/API_PutRecord.html#Streams-PutRecord-request-SequenceNumberForOrdering) parameter

Answer (score 1):

On the **producer** side, the records that are placed on the same shard are sequential.

But, if multiple records pushed to the stream are placed on different shards, and the ordering is important to you; you should check "ApproximateArrivalTimestamp" value of each record on the **consumer** side.

In Java, that timestamp value is java.util.Date and the resolution is in milliseconds.

> Each Amazon Kinesis record includes a value,
>   ApproximateArrivalTimestamp, that is set when a stream successfully
>   receives and stores a record. This is commonly referred to as a
>   server-side timestamp, whereas a client-side timestamp is set when a
>   data producer creates or sends the record to a stream (a data producer
>   is any data source putting data records into a stream, for example
>   with PutRecords). The timestamp has millisecond precision. There are
>   no guarantees about the timestamp accuracy, or that the timestamp is
>   always increasing. For example, records in a shard or across a stream
>   might have timestamps that are out of order.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/kinesis/latest/APIReference/API_GetRecords.html